# Alerting lat/lon value on Bing Map programmatically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Running

`javascript: alert(document.getElementById('srchssubTitle').value)`

at

http://www.bing.com/maps/#Y3A9NTIuMDYzNjAyfi0wLjc3Nzg5NCZsdmw9MTUmc3R5PXImZW89MCZxPU1LMyUyMDVKRQ==

returns me an `unidentified value` message, even though I've checked the page source code and found that I referring to the correct id

`<span class="ssubLatLon" id="srchssubTitle">51.990376,-0.761363</span>`.

How do I get JavaScript to properly echo this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `innerHTML` property:

```
javascript: alert(document.getElementById('srchssubTitle').innerHTML);
```